# Azure Cognitive Search - how to prevent searching for plural form also returning singular matches

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

We have an Azure Cognitive Search index that we use for full text searches.
Currently, when the user searches for a plural word (e.g. Buildings), the singular forms are also being matched (building).
We want to restrict this behaviour so that only the plural matches are returned.
I've read through the odata documentation but cannot find any reference to how we could accomplish this either through parameters in the search.ismatch in the filter or in the index config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plural and singular forms are likely both matching because the field is configured with the default language analyzer, which performs stemming of terms. If you're looking for an exact match, you can use the 'eq' operator in a filter. If you want a case-insensitive (but otherwise exact) match, you can try [normalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-normalizers) (note that this feature is in preview at the time of this writing.)

If you need matching behaviour that is somewhat more sophisticated than a case-insensitive match, you should look into [custom analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers). They allow you to customize the behaviour of tokenization, as well as selectively use (or not use) stemming and other lexical analysis techniques.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback Bruce.  I ended up creating a simple customer analyser without any stemming options which appears to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Just out of interest, we use a C# console app to create and populate our index - are the normalizers available yet in the Azure.Search.Documents nuget libraries?

Comment: I'll check on that and get back to you.

Comment: There is a beta of the .NET SDK that supports normalizers: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Search.Documents_11.4.0-beta.5/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/CHANGELOG.md#1140-beta3-2021-09-07

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Bruce's answer,

Custom normalizers support many of the same token and character filters as custom analyzers do. In order to decide which one best fits your needs, consider the following questions:

1. Will this plural/singular matching behaviour be used in filtering/sorting/faceting operations? If so, pre-configured or custom normalizers will enable you to refine what results are returned by your [search filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters). You can build your own or choose from the list of pre-configured ones, and it supports more than case insensitivity. See the list of supported [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#supported-char-filters) and [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#supported-token-filters) filters.
2. Will you need this plural/singular matching behaviour in full-text search, regardless of whether a filter is used? If so, consider using the custom analyzer Bruce suggested above.

Afaik, please note that normalizers will only affect filtering/sorting/faceting results. Also, normalizers are the only way to perform this "normalization" to filter/sort/facet queries. Setting an analyzer will not affect these types of queries.